# Редактирование select через left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

есть несколько таблиц (3), вывожу их вместе через left join, все хорошо, но возник такой вопрос. У меня выводится куча лишних строк, буд-то происходит вывод каждый с каждым, не подскажите, как это улучшить?
Делаю вывод следующим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM in_fileindex_main main 
    LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_additionaly addit ON (main.DocumentNumber = addit.DocumentNumber) 
    LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_applicability app ON (main.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber)
    WHERE 1
```

И вывод происходит примерно следующим образом:

```
------------------------------- -----------
|main_1|main_2|add_1|add_2|app_1|app_2|
---------------------------------------
|text1 |text2 |  1  |  2  |  x  |  z  |
---------------------------------------
|text1 |text2 |  1  |  2  |  y  |  c  |
---------------------------------------
|text1 |text2 |  3  |  4  |  x  |  z  |
---------------------------------------
|text1 |text2 |  3  |  4  |  y  |  c  |
```

Как видно, что вторая и четвертая строки являются лишними и данные "3" и "4", можно записать во вторую строку и смысл не изменится, т.к. строки побочных таблиц у меня не связаны между собой, они связаны только с главной по номеру.
А мне нужно, чтобы вывелось примерно следующим образом:

```
    ------------------------------- -------
    |main_1|main_2|add_1|add_2|app_1|app_2|
    ---------------------------------------
    |text1 |text2 |  1  |  2  |  x  |  z  |
    ---------------------------------------
    |text1 |text2 |  3  |  4  |  y  |  c  |
    ---------------------------------------
```

Можно ли это как-то реализовать?

Comment: `Как видно, что третья и четвертая строки являются лишними` - совсем не видно. Там другие наборы данных.

Comment: @Мелкий я согласен, я имел ввиду, "условно лишние" так сказать

Comment: И мне всё равно непонятно почему они какие-то "условно лишние", что бы это ни значило.

Comment: @Мелкий Я добавил рисунок таблицы, как я это примерно вижу, и что мне нужно получтиь

Comment: так почему не должна выводиться строка ```|text1 |text2 |  1  |  2  |  y  |  c  |```? Она отличается от всех остальных строк. По какому условию нужно отбирать строки? ну и у вас в примере явно не соответствие. вы пишите, что 3 и 4 строка лишние, но тут же просите вывести 1 и 3 строки. Так что именно нужно?

Comment: Поля app_1, app_2 обязательно выбирать? Если да - как решить, какие именно берем? Любые?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT * FROM in_fileindex_main main 
LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_additionaly addit ON (main.DocumentNumber = addit.DocumentNumber) 
LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_applicability app ON (main.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber AND addit.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber)
WHERE 1
```

либо

```
SELECT * FROM in_fileindex_main main 
    LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_additionaly addit ON (main.DocumentNumber = addit.DocumentNumber) 
    LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_applicability app ON (main.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber)
    WHERE (app.DocumentNumber ISNULL OR addit.DocumentNumber IS NULL OR addit.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber)
```

Comment: тоже самое получается(

Comment: Я добавил рисунок таблицы, как я это примерно вижу

Comment: Измените условие в конце = на <>

Comment: В каком из двух примеров?

Comment: или в обоих примерах, в этом месте ?addit.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber

Comment: Да чтоб они не совпадали в этом месте

Comment: теперь вместо данных из третьей таблицы стоят NULL во всех полях

Comment: Ну тогда былоб хорошо если б вы расписали таблицы с полями и данными